# Strange duplication of variables when including into bashrc file

Tags: bash, bashrc

*pls see the update below*

My `bashrc` has the line `. ./bash_path_vars`, where `bash_path_vars` contains:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

But what I get in the new terminal is:

```
> echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib
```

(duplication)

If you put that export statement directly inside `bashrc`, there is no duplication!

I am puzzled. Why does this happen?

**UPDATE**: I am stupid, I had `. ./bash_path_vars` two times in two different places. Of course, it resulted in duplication... Thanks to every one who replied to this question and sorry for not asking a better question!

Comment: put it this way: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`, then `export  PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PATH`

Comment: Please post the entry for `.bash_paths` as entered in `.bashrc`

Comment: BTW, you should probably change `./bash_path_vars` to `~/bash_path_vars` to avoid issues when restarting the shell outside of `$HOME`.

Comment: I just tried a setup like yours (with the path file and source statement in bashrc), and got duplication! It was because I already exported the variable and restarted the shell (`exec bash`), so it inherited the variables from the last shell, instead of starting fresh. Try logging out and back in, which will end all current shell sessions.

Answer (score 1):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

This command does not just set or overwrite LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but rather takes the existing variable and expands it with :/usr/local/lib

Take a look at .bash_profile and /etc/profile, whether the variable is also set there. You could also set:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr/local/lib
```

in bashrc.

Comment: yes, I am aware that the command just appends to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` --- that is intended. No, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set anywhere else (I also tried to use some funny path instead of `/usr/local/lib` --- the same effect, it gets duplicated). Don't you get the duplication on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

Your are doing it wrongly. Please note that `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is already a variable declared some where, so when you do:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

You are saying, expand `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and add `/usr/local/lib` so you will get what your currently seeing:

```
> echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib
```

Now change your entry in the `.bashrc` file to:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PATH
```

Now when you run: `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, you should see `/usr/local/lib`

Merely putting: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` will give you the desired result, but adding the second line (`export PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PATH`) puts that *variable* in your *system path*.

Comment: sorry, not clear, why do I get duplication? (yes, I want to expand the old value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (which _does not have_ `/usr/...`), and then append a new entry to it). Thanks!

Comment: The reason is simple you have `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib`, in there you have two declarations of `/usr/local/lib`. One plane `/usr/local/lib`, and another represented as `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is link when you use `1 += 1`. You are simply adding `/usr/local/lib` unto itself

Comment: Please be more explicit, what do you mean by `/user/...`? Give an example...